# Mongodb query subtree from parent node id

Tags: mongodb

I have a nested tree structure that is saved to Mongo like displayed in the example. Is there a way to aggregate the entire subtree when given a parent id?

In this example the stored data looks like this:

```
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "Node A",
    children: [{
        _id: "2",
        name: "Node B",
        children: []
    }]
},
{
    _id: "2",
    name: "Node B",
    children: [{
        _id: "3",
        name: "Node C",
        children: []
    }]
},
{
    _id: "3",
    name: "Node C",
    children: []
}
```

The query result should look like this if possible:

```
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "Node A",
    children: [
    {
        _id: "2",
        name: "Node B",
        children: [
            _id: "3",
            name: "Node C",
            children: []
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried a graphlookup like this with no success

```
{ 
    $graphLookup: { 
        from: 'nodes', 
        startWith: '$children', 
        connectFromField: 'children', 
        connectToField: '_id', 
        as: 'children' 
    } 
}
```